# How do I say if record empty yes else no in a view?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

In my codeigniter PHP model I have

```
if  ($this->input->post('questions') != "")
        {
            if($this->input->post('questions') == "Yes")
            {
                $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions !=',"");
                $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions IS NOT ', null, false);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions',"");
                $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions IS', null, true);
            }
```

Yet when I run a 
 `echo $this->db->last_query();` I get this error

```
'Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

SELECT * FROM (`health_professional`) JOIN `webinar_event` ON `webinar_event`.`hpid` = `health_professional`.`hpid` WHERE `webinar_event`.`questions` = '' AND `webinar_event`.`questions` IS

Filename: D:\Development\PfizerWebinar\web\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330'
```

Basically what I am trying to do is make it a if I search for "did ask question" I get anything that isnt null and if I want to search for if they did ask a question show me all the ones that are not null.

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->where('webinar_event.questions IS NULL', null, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try this 


      if  ($this->input->post('questions') != "")
      {
        if($this->input->post('questions') == "Yes")
        {
            $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions !=',"");
            $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions IS NOT NULL', null, false);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions',"");
            $this->db->where('webinar_event.questions IS NULL', null, true);
        }
      }
```

Comment: solved thanks I realized what my error was before I checked. I needed IS NOT NULL and IS NULL at the end. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($var)){
  //do stuff
}
```

here we check if the variable is not empty hence the !
   or you can use:

```
if(isset($var)){
 //do stuff
}
```

this checks if the variable is set.
or:

```
if(is_null($var)){

}else{
  //do stuff
}
```

whichever you preffer, or a combination of isset and !empty is usually what I go for.